# ScriptService execute eating memory

Tags: c#, google-api, mono

When I run Execute on a ScriptService run request, it takes some memory and fails to release it.  Testing this by running on monodevelop on a Raspberry Pi shows the memory rising at an alarming rate, and will eventually crash the program.  The GC.Collect was an attempt at re-claiming this memory.  Is there any insight into what I am doing wrong?

```
public MainWindow() : base(Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
{
    Build();

    while (true)
    {
        getDashRow();

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Total available memory before collection: {0:N0}", System.GC.GetTotalMemory(false));

        System.GC.Collect();

        Console.WriteLine("Total available memory collection: {0:N0}", System.GC.GetTotalMemory(true));
    }
 }

 private int getDashRow()
 {
    ScriptsResource.RunRequest runreq;
    DriveService driveservice;
    ExecutionRequest exrequest;

    Console.WriteLine("getDashRow");
    int retval = 0;

    exrequest = new ExecutionRequest();
    exrequest.Function = "getMacRow";
    IList<object> parameters = new List<object>();
    parameters.Add(spreadsheetname);
    exrequest.Parameters = parameters;
    exrequest.DevMode = false;

    try
    {
        // run a Google Apps Script function on the online sheet to find number of rows (more efficient)
        runreq = scriptservice.Scripts.Run(exrequest, dashscriptid);

        // following line consumes the memory
        Operation op = runreq.Execute();

        retval = Convert.ToInt16(op.Response["result"]);
        parameters = null;
        exrequest = null;
        op = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("getDashRow: " + ex.Message);
    }

    return retval;
}
```

Comment: If you have a memory issue, you need to use a memory profiler

Comment: I used the mono profiler and all that really told me was that memory consumption was increasing while the program running.  I already know which line creates the consumption as commented in the code sample, what I don't know is how to clear that used memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this, installing Mono Preview v6.0.0.277 has resolved this problem, memory is now correctly freed up without manually calling GC.Collect().

[Related issue which led to the solution](https://forums.homeseer.com/forum/internet-or-network-related-plug-ins/internet-or-network-discussion/ak-google-calendar-alexbk66/1299258-can%E2%80%99t-install-the-plugin-on-linux?p=1301673#post1301673)